# Java thread generate same value

Tags: java, multithreading

```
   public class ThinkThreadLocal {

        public static int data;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                new Thread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        data = new Random().nextInt();
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " gene data:" + data);
                    }

                }).start();
            }
        }
   }
```

Why it prints the same value?

```
Thread-0 gene data:-751128970
Thread-1 gene data:-751128970
```

Comment: @saka1029 yes, but if you create the Random with the default constructor they will not be created with the same seed.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the thread that will be executed second is setting the value of `data` before the first thread is printing anything. Making a minor modification to your code illustrates this quite well:

```
public final class ThinkThreadLocal {

    public static int data;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int temp = data = new Random().nextInt();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " temp: " + temp);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " shared: " + data);
                }

            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

One execution of this gave me:

```
Thread-0 temp: 709919531
Thread-1 temp: 2022218312
Thread-0 shared: 2022218312
Thread-1 shared: 2022218312
```

As you can see, the values being generated are different (709919531 and 2022218312 in this case), but `data` is being overwritten with the second value before the first value is printed. This shows it is unrelated to the seed of `Random`.

A second way to show this is to synchronize on the class itself, which (in this case) will block the thread that gets executed second until the first has finished executing:

```
public final class ThinkThreadLocal {

    public static int data;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (ThinkThreadLocal.class) {
                        data = new Random().nextInt();
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " shared: " + data);
                    }
                }

            }).start();
        }
    }

}
```

which resulted in

```
Thread-0 shared: 1811879710
Thread-1 shared: 1738616729
```

Answer (score 1):

Class `Random` is a [pseudo-random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). It starts from some seed value. If you don't specify the seed explicitly, <strike>it takes the current time as the seed.</strike>

<strike>If you very quickly create two `Random` objects, they will be created with the same seed value, and they will generate the same sequence of random numbers.</strike> - edit: K Erlandsson is right; this isn't really true...

Don't create a new `Random` object every time you want to generate a random number.

There is just one static variable `data`, which you are using in both threads. They will both write to and read from the same variable.

Better version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            private final Random random = new Random();

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int data = random.nextInt();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " gene data:" + data);
            }

        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Random class (at least on my JVM) does not get the same sequence even if you create the Random objects the same nansecod. Something like this: `this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());` is done when creating a Random object where seedUniquifier makes sure two consequent creates does not yield the same seed.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning your random value to a static field. You should make the data variable a local variable, i.e. `int data = new Random().nextInt();`

Using new instances of `Random` is not really a problem (although it is bad design) since the default constructor make pretty sure different seeds will be used.

From the javadoc of the default constructor.

> Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed
>   of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct
>   from any other invocation of this constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Toby, it's unrelated to seed. If you remove the shared static variable data, then it's always generate different number

```
public class ThinkThreadLocal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " gene data:" + new Random().nextInt());
                }

            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

> Output: Thread-0 gene data:1062913479 Thread-1 gene data:-599634908

Answer (score 0):

Correcting @Jesper's solution, Random object must be the same object for both threads in order to work as you expect...

```
public class ThinkThreadLocal {

        public static int data;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            final Random random = new Random();
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                new Thread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        data = random.nextInt();
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " gene data:" + data);
                    }

                }).start();
            }
        }
```